# Mesh is not displayed correctly

Tags: modeling, mesh

I'm tryng to model a character and would like to know how can I fix the mesh that you can see on the attached screenshots,because it is not complete and wrong. Thanks.

[image: mesh wrong pic. 1]

[image: mesh wrong pic. 2]

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "fix", but if you mean corner of the mesh in the screenshot center then it maybe a way to go is to add face loop to its bottom (instead of sharp edge loop), and lower amount of loop cuts. That part is not connected to the rest of mesh for some reason, if you wish to you could reconnect them by changing topology of that unconnected part.